# Where is pow function defined and implemented in C?

Tags: c, function, declare, pow

I read that the pow(double, double) function is defined in "math.h" but I can't find its declaration.

Does anybody know where this function declared? And where is it implemented in C?

Reference:

> http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/maths_functions.html

Comment: If it's not directly in `math.h` a decent editor with tagging capability (or similar) will take you right to the declaration as long as you tag the include file directory for your C runtime library.  Pretty much any decent programming editor will have this capability.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using, but it looks like for MSVC 9 the source for `pow()` isn't included. The implementation seems to be in a library `tran.lib` for which source is not included.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requests for assistance in finding off-site resources (like specific source code!) are categorically off-topic. (Only you know which libc you're compiling against, whether source to that libc is published, &c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C library source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214325/c-library-source-code)

Answer (score 9):

Quite often, an include file such as `<math.h>` will include other header files that actually declare the functions you would expect to see in `<math.h>`. The idea is that the program gets what it expects when it includes `<math.h>`, even if the actual function definitions are in some other header file.

Finding the *implementation* of a standard library function such as `pow()` is quite another matter. You will have to dig up the source code to your C standard runtime library and find the implementation in there.

Comment: Note that most compilers do provide source to the library.  But it can sometimes be quite a maze.

Answer (score 4):

Where it's defined depends on your environment. The code is inside a compiled C standard library somewhere.

Its "definition" is in the source code for your c standard library distribution. One such distribution is eglibc. This is browsable online, or in a source distribution:

[w_pow.c](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_10/libc/math/w_pow.c?rev=8421&view=markup)

[math_private.h](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_10/libc/math/math_private.h?rev=8421&view=markup)

Short answer: In the C standard library source code.

Comment: w_pow.c is not a very useful link as it basically just calls `__ieee754_pow(x, y);` which is the real definition...

Answer (score 3):

The actual implementation of `pow` may vary from compiler to compiler.  Generally, math.h (or a vendor-specific file included by math.h) provides the *prototype* for `pow` (i.e., its declaration), but the implementation is buried in some library file such as libm.a.  Depending on your compiler, the actual source code for `pow` or any other library function may not be available.

Answer (score 3):

**declared:** in the include directory of your system/SDK (e.g.: /usr/include;/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/include/architecture/arm/math.h)

**defined (implemented):**

- as *library* (compiled, binary code): in the library directory of your system/SDK (e.g.: /usr/lib (in case of the math library it's libm.dylib)
- as source (program code): this is the interesting part. I work on a Mac OS X 10.6.x right now. The *sources* for the functions declared in math.h (e.g.: extern double pow ( double, double ); ) are not shipped with the installation (at least I couldn't find it). You are likely to find those sources in your system/SDK's C library. In my case the math library (libm) is a separate project, some of its sources are provided by Apple: http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libm/Libm-315.tar.gz

The extern keyword in the function declaration of pow means, that it's defined somewhere else. Math functions are low-level high-performance implementations mostly done in assembly code (*.s). The assembly routines (taking the arguments/giving the parameters via registers/stack) are linked with the rest of the C library. The linking/exporting of the function/routine names is platform specific and doesn't really matter if ones goal is not dive into assembly coding.

I hope this helped,
Raphael

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeking how the calculation is implemented, you can find it here:
http://fossies.org/dox/gcc-4.5.3/e__pow_8c_source.html
The name of the function is __ieee754_pow
which is called by pow function.

Answer (score 1):

I’s really defined in `math.h`. Have you tried including `math.h` and simply using `pow`? What do you mean by “can't find it”?

Comment: Yes, I can use it but can't find its declaration. Can somebody find its declaration and implementation in math.h? Please post it here. thanks.

Comment: For example, isless function is declared as:
# ifndef isless
#  define isless(x, y) \
  (__extension__             \
   ({ __typeof__(x) __x = (x); __typeof__(y) __y = (y);         \
      !isunordered (__x, __y) && __x < __y; }))
# endif

I expect similar thing that happens to pow(double, double)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C implementation for fdlibm:  http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c

For what it's worth, when v8 dropped its cos/sine tables, it pulled from fdlibm's implementation to do so:  https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=22918

From the change commit comments:  "Implement trigonometric functions using a fdlibm port."

Mozilla on the other hand calls the cstdlib math functions, which will have variable performance by build and system (ex: may or may not invoke the chip-level implementations of transcendental functions).  While C# bytecode seems to make explicit references to chip-level functions when it can.  However, "pow" is not one of those, iirc (doesn't seem to have an chip-level function) and is implemented elsewhere.

See also:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=967709

For a cos/sine discussion in the Mozilla community, comparison of Mozilla's implementation vs old v8 implementation.

See also:  [How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)

Intrinsic functions are chip-level, actually implemented on the processor.  (We don't necessarily need lookup tables any more.)

Answer (score 0):

Its [here](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/math.h.html) and also [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/math.h.html).
Also go on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math.h)

You will find pow there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implement of powq in [GNU gcc-13](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libquadmath/math/powq.c;h=b825020743131d9526f80b7c07556b8f925388f0;hb=refs/heads/releases/gcc-13).

The core idea of the implement is at the top of the code:

```
 powq(x,y) return x**y

              n
 Method:  Let x =  2   * (1+f)
    1. Compute and return log2(x) in two pieces:
        log2(x) = w1 + w2,
       where w1 has 113-53 = 60 bit trailing zeros.
    2. Perform y*log2(x) = n+y' by simulating muti-precision
       arithmetic, where |y'|<=0.5.
    3. Return x**y = 2**n*exp(y'*log2)
```

Noted that `pow` we use more often is implemented by hardware or `libm`, C compiler only make an alias for them.