# C library source code

Tags: c

I want to find the C libraries' source code to find out more about the functions used.Is GCC the only resource I can count on?I couldn't use the doxygen html version of the GCC libraries,to tell the truth it seems complex to me,for example I couldn't find the printf function's source code(Was I looking in the wrong place?).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The C library source code is not part of the GCC distribution. GCC can work with myriad C libraries (even the one shipped with Windows), all distributed separately.

Answer (score 7):

OTOH, in addition to [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/):

- [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/)
- [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/)
- [BSD libc](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/)

Answer (score 6):

Reading the source code is one thing. Reading a good book that includes source code is another thing entirely. And I'm not sure you can do better than [The Standard C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099), by PJ Plauger. It's 20 years old, but for me it's still a page-turner.

Man, I feel old.

Answer (score 4):

The GNU version is here:

Info:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Download:
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to narrow down your question a bit. The implementation varies. Not everything related to implementation details (perhaps pretty much all of it - someone with more standard knowledge can chip in) is prescribed by the C/C++ standard.

In the end you may understand how a particular library decided to do it. It's still useful knowledge, but not THE answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find the `printf` function's source code

Here is the source code for this function, it seems to be calling to `__vbprintf_internal`, which is found [*`glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c`*](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c.html). `Glibc` source code is also available in [`bootlin`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.33/source), I think  it is more readable and convenient code.

```c
int __printf (const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  int done;
  va_start (arg, format);
  done = __vfprintf_internal (stdout, format, arg, 0);
  va_end (arg);
  return done;
}
```

[*`glibc/stdio-common/printf.c`*](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/printf.c.html)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest standard C library I've ever seen is Minix's standard library.

I ported it on at least 3 toolchains with virtually no effort.

I actually grew up with that library.