# Where are all the functions in C/C++ defined?

Tags: c++, c

I was exploring the include folder in dev c++ compiler.There i could find .h files where all the function and constants were present but I couldn't find there definition.They were preceded by extern keyword,So they must be defined somewhere else externally.Can anyone tell me where to look for them?I just want to see the functions working mechanism.

Comment: The answer depends on your OS and compiler vendor.

Comment: Dev c++ for Windows

Comment: Dev-C++ is not a compiler. You're probably using GCC. Since you're on Windows you *shall not* have access to the implementation of the C library! The C++ library that is packaged with GCC can be found in the Dev-C++ installation directory somewhere.

Comment: Generally speaking, the implementations are compiled already, given to you as a runtime library.  E.g. on Linux we have libc and libstdc++. On windows there is msvcrt.

Comment: similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214325/c-library-source-code

Comment: What if its Ubuntu?Where can i find it?

Comment: You can get the source to glibc here: git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git  Note that it can be rather complex to follow since it supports a large set of platforms and performance trumps readability.

Comment: For learning purposes, Plauger's book "The Standard C Library" is  quite nice.  Also if you install any version of Visual C++ you can configure the installation to include the runtime library source code for that platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean the standard library functions. C functions are defined in the source files that were used to compile the standard library; these may or may not be distributed with your compiler toolchain.

C++ standard library functions and classes are mostly defined in the headers that you can find in the `include` directory, as you said. This is because much of the C++ standard is composed of template classes and functions, which must be implemented in the same translation unit that they are declared in. Some platform-specific functions (like threading and I/O) are implemented in external source files, which again may or may not distributed with your compiler toolchain.