# Math.Atan2 and FPATAN

Tags: c#, .net, x86, trigonometry

I'm writing some math code in C#, forcing it to compile for x86 in release, optimized, and I'm looking at the disassembly in windbg.  It's usually pretty good, often writing better assembly than I could (not that I'm all that good at assembly, but there you go).

However, I've noticed that this function:

```
static void TemporaryWork()
{
    double x = 4;
    double y = 3;
    double z = Math.Atan2(x, y);
}
```

Is producing this disassembly:

```
001f0078 55              push    ebp
001f0079 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
001f007b dd05a0001f00    fld     qword ptr ds:[1F00A0h]
001f0081 83ec08          sub     esp,8
001f0084 dd1c24          fstp    qword ptr [esp]
001f0087 dd05a8001f00    fld     qword ptr ds:[1F00A8h]
001f008d 83ec08          sub     esp,8
001f0090 dd1c24          fstp    qword ptr [esp]
001f0093 e86e9ba66f      call    clr!GetHashFromBlob+0x94e09 (6fc59c06) (System.Math.Atan2(Double, Double), mdToken: 06000de7)
001f0098 ddd8            fstp    st(0)
001f009a 5d              pop     ebp
001f009b c3              ret
```

Even if you're not an x86 guru, you'll notice something odd in there: there's a call to System.Math.Atan2.  As in a function call.

But there's actually an x86 opcode that would do that: [FPATAN](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap10.htm#fpatan)

Why is the JITer calling a function when there's an actual assembly instruction to do the operation?  I thought that System.Math was basically a wrapper for native assembly instructions.  Most of the operations in there have direct assembly opcodes.  But that's apparently not the case?

Does anyone have any information on why the JITer isn't/can't perform this rather obvious optimization?

Comment: If I google `bug in fpatan` I get some results for it for some processor models, so it could be `Math.Atan2` works around these bugs and was a replacement for it in `Math.Atan`. I am not really sure but perhaps it could be the direction to look for? Good question.

Comment: "Does anyone have any information on why the JITer isn't/can't perform this rather obvious optimization?”  I won’t pretend to speak for the JIT in question, but as someone who has implemented `atan2` for multiple platforms, calling the FPATAN instruction would be an obvious *pessimization*.  FPATAN is much slower than a good software implementation, even including function-call overhead. (150-300 cycles vs. 50-100 cycles, depending on the specific library and hardware in question).

Answer (score 6):

You can chase down the reason from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870593/17034), it shows how these math functions are mapped by the jitter.

Which takes you to clr/src/classlibnative/float/comfloat.cpp, ComDouble::Atan2() function.  Which explains the reason:

```
   // the intrinsic for Atan2 does not produce Nan for Atan2(+-inf,+-inf)
   if (IS_DBL_INFINITY(x) && IS_DBL_INFINITY(y)) {
       return(x / y);      // create a NaN
   }
   return (double) atan2(x, y);
```

So it is a workaround to fix FPU behavior that is not CLI compliant.

Comment: I would not say anything is being fixed here. It is an adapter rather than a fixer.

Comment: Ah cool, but following the source I don't think that's necessarily the reason.  It looks like there's a lot of functions that aren't getting mapped to intrinsics, but they aren't doing anything extra.  For instance, COMDouble::Log literally just calls intrinsic log.  From ecall.cpp, only sin, cos, sqrt, round, and abs are getting mapped directly to intrinsics.

Comment: You can see the code for ComDouble::Exp and Log as well, again with a comment.  It notes that the SSE2 version of them is too slow and Exp has a similar domain problem.  They do **not** use an intrisic, it calls the CRT versions of these functions.  Hand-crafted assembly code from Intel.  If you have a better theory than the pretty explicit comments then we'd love to hear it.

Comment: I saw the comment, but it looks like it's talking about fpfast vs fpprecise.  AFAIK the math functions in math.h _are_ intrinsics, at least in the sense that they get replaced by opcodes by the compiler in all the platforms I've looked on (which admittedly isn't a lot).  And as near as I can tell comfloat.cpp's math functions (log, exp, etc.) are being pulled in from common.h, which pull them in from math.h.

Comment: I already mentioned that in several places, they are **not** intrinsics.  Just write a little test C program to find out for yourself.

Comment: You're right, so now I'm even more confused.  Why all the extra overhead, even in C land?  Why not just straight up replace the calls with the FPU instructions?

Comment: @JayLemmon: The `fpatan` instruction implemented by microcode on modern CPUs isn't super fast.  Inlining x87 instructions is not necessarily the best way to implement a match library, except for primitive operations like `fsqrt` / `fmul` / `fadd` that CPUs do implement directly in hardware, not through microcode.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  (Or with SSE2 or AVX, using those instead of obsolete x87).  If the accuracy / performance tradeoff of an x87 instruction happens to match what you want, sometimes they're worth using.  But not using them is a very reasonable decision.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thanks for the explanation.  At the time I was under the impression that any instruction in the x87 instruction set would be implemented in hardware, but that's obviously not always the case.