# Math library against own library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, math

So we tried developing a math class in C# and we did.
Comparing results with the original math class for System.Math shows that we are always a little or a lot slower (trig methods particularly).

But the wonder comes when we are using basic methods like absolute value which does not contain loads of code apart from

```
if(value < 0) return -value;
else return value;
```

and still we are far behind.

I cannot make this abs method any smaller, using the ternary operator will not help either I guess.

Is it because the System.Math would be written in C?
Would it go faster if we write it in native language, though it seems it won't change much I read.
Finally, could a dll work faster than a class and if so why and if not… well why too?

Comment: Above all, it is just more readable.

Comment: Did you NGEN your library? Because System.Math has native images which is faster

Comment: Your absolute value implementation contains a bug, by the way.

Comment: what about `int.MinValue`? :)

Comment: There may be a bug, it was more of an example. I may have a look at the NGEN, though I think in the end we will use the System.Math, it was more of a trial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing with [Servé's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870656/math-library-against-own-library-in-c-sharp#comment27847865_18870764) that shows the CLR is written in C++, you'll find that `Math.Abs` calls [fabs or fabsf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18z15bk0.aspx).

```
FCIntrinsicSig("Abs", &gsig_SM_Flt_RetFlt, COMDouble::AbsFlt, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Abs)
FCIntrinsicSig("Abs", &gsig_SM_Dbl_RetDbl, COMDouble::AbsDbl, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_Abs)
```

```
/*=====================================AbsFlt=====================================
**
==============================================================================*/
FCIMPL1_V(float, COMDouble::AbsFlt, float f) 
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    FCUnique(0x14);
    return fabsf(f);
FCIMPLEND

/*=====================================AbsDbl=====================================
**
==============================================================================*/
FCIMPL1_V(double, COMDouble::AbsDbl, double d) 
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    return fabs(d);
FCIMPLEND
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think trivial functions in System.Math are written in C because the overhead of calling out to C would be in many cases much too high. Maybe they are written in raw IL to make them extra fast.

BTW: Why would you write your own math library? This is almost never a good idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework  Math is written in C++

Comment: It is part of a project for learning. Indeed, there is no reason to do so since System.Math is already having all that is needed, but it was just a way to learn Taylor series and other algorithm and see how methods are implemented.