# C# Math.Pow(-2,1.1) > n.def

Tags: c#, math, type-conversion, pow

I just found out that when entering a negative x and a decimal y, [`Math.Pow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the not-defined value as result, which is wrong I guess. Calculating this in other programs, even like the windows Calculator works with a correct result. Also this case is not mentioned in the documentation.

Target Framework is 4.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It will be complex number: `(-2)^1.1 =  -2.0386 - 0.6624i`.

Comment: How is this not covered in the documentation? "x < 0 but not **NegativeInfinity**; y is not an integer, **NegativeInfinity**, or **PositiveInfinity**." - Return value is **NaN**

Comment: What do you mean that Windows Calculator works? It says "Invalid Input" for me.

Comment: Remember that `X^1.1 == (X^(11/10)) == (X^(1/10))^11` so if X is negative you will be taking the 10th root of it, which yields a complex number as Ulugbek states.

Comment: Remember parenthesis in situations where infix operator `^` is used, like Windows Calculator. So `(-2)^1.1`, not just `- 2^1.1`. Raising a negative quantity to a non-integral power requires choosing a branch. There are different conventions. As @LasseV.Karlsen said, Windows Calculator won't do `(-2)^1.1`. It will do `(-2)^1.2`, however, and it calculates it as if `(-2)^1.2 = (-2)^(6/5) = ((-2)^6)^(1/5) = (+64)^(1/5)`. So it gets a real (not imaginary) result for that. Some other software chooses another branch and yields a complex number for `(-2)^1.2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is going to be complex number, so you have to use `Complex` class from `System.Numerics` namespace.

```
Complex n = new Complex(-2, 0);
Complex result = Complex.Pow(n, 1.1);
```

In case if result is **real** number (**integer** power), then you can use `Math.Pow`.

As @JeppeStigNielsen mentioned, the conversion from `int`/`double` to `Complex` is implicit, so the code can be shortened to:

```
Complex result = Complex.Pow(-2, 1.1);
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning `Complex.Pow`. More simply, you can write `Complex.Pow(-2, 1.1)`, the conversion from real `double` (or actually real `int` in this case) to `Complex` is implicit. Note that complex exponentiation requires choosing a branch. For some inputs, like `Complex.Pow(-2, 1.2)`, the result differs from Windows Calculator, `(-2)^1.2`.

Answer (score 1):

> Also this case is not mentioned in the documentation

You sure? From it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Parameters
>
> x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer,
> NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.
>
> Return value
>
> NaN

I'm not sure which OS you tried but it doesn't work in calc.exe (Win7 - 64bit) says *Invalid Input*.

As Ulugbek [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23559155/447156), taking `1.1` power of a negative value creates a complex number. Because (-2)<sup>1.1</sup> = (-2)<sup>11/10</sup> = (-2)<sup>1/10<sup>11</sup></sup> and getting `10` times rooth of `-2` returns a complex number.

Since `Math.Pow` takes and returns `double` values, this doesn't fit with requirements. You can use [`Complex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class from [`System.Numerics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2^1.1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%5E1.1)

[image]

Further reading: [How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)