# An efficient way to implement power function: Why Math.Exp(x * Math.Log(n)) is faster than Math.Pow()?

Tags: c#, math, biginteger, bigdecimal

I'm trying to solve this problem in C# using these 2 approaches:

```
public double NormalPowerMethod(double x, double toPower)
{
    return Math.Pow(x, toPower);
}

public double EfficientPowerMethod(double x, double toPower)
{
    return Math.Exp(Math.Log(x) * toPower);
}
```

[I ran a simple test program](https://github.com/diophung/common-problems/blob/master/CommonProblems/CommonProblems/Program.cs) :

```
EfficientPower ep = new EfficientPower();
Console.WriteLine("Enter x:");
double x = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter power: ");
int toPower = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} to the power of {1}= {2}", x,toPower, ep.NormalPowerMethod(x,toPower)));
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Normal power time =" + timer.ElapsedTicks);

//-------------- efficient
timer.Reset();
timer.Start();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Efficient power: {0} to the power of {1}= {2}", x, toPower, ep.EfficientPowerMethod(x, toPower)));
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Efficient power time =" + timer.ElapsedTicks);

Console.ReadLine();
```

and I noticed :

- `Math.pow(x,y)` is slower than `Math.Exp(Math.log(x) * y)`

For e.g:

```
Enter x:
15
Enter power:
26
Normal power: 15 to the power of 26= 3.78767524410635E+30
Normal power time =818
Efficient power: 15 to the power of 26= 3.78767524410634E+30
Efficient power time =533


Enter x:
1024
Enter power:
1024
Normal power: 1024 to the power of 1024= Infinity
Normal power time =810
Efficient power: 1024 to the power of 1024= Infinity
Efficient power time =519
```

Why such behaviour ? I thought more calculation will be slower ?

Comment: I am not sure if your measurement is correct. You have to run this at least a few times to get decent measurements.

Comment: One measurement is no measurement.

Comment: Take a look at this series - http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/

Comment: I will include a proper test suite - but trust me, I have tried extreme cases : from pow(0,0) to extreme large pow(10240,10240) - the result is the same (well if the Stopwatch class in MSDN is trust-worthy)

Comment: Hans answered your question I believe

Comment: Cool, thanks @SriramSakthivel - I was trying to find the similar questions. Fair enough.

Comment: I did a proper test and results show that efficient is a little more efficient than normal. If reopened, I will include test results and code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:  do you mind forward your test case to phungkimcuong AT gmail DOT com ? I'm reading Hans' answer on the other topic and figuring out wth happened

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework) is asking about "How to make it faster" , whereas I am asking about "Why is it faster" - I'm pretty sure which one is faster. 

Furthermore, Hans' answer did not justify "why" the latter method is faster. So please consider re-open my question, or please suggest how should I edit the question to avoid being marked as duplicate?

Comment: I thought you'll get all the info you require over there. If not I'll reopen. I agree that is not a exact duplicate. I'll reopen in a moment. Sorry anyway..

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct measurement script, since we already discusses your measurement is off:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        Math.Pow(10, 100);
    }

    TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - start;
    Console.WriteLine("Normal: {0:N0}", diff.TotalMilliseconds);

    //-------------- efficient
    start = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        Math.Exp(Math.Log(10) * 100);
    }

    diff = DateTime.Now - start;
    Console.WriteLine("Efficient: {0:N0}", diff.TotalMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output with 10.000.000 tries (statistics are consistent after numerous tries):

```
Normal:    1.968 ms.
Efficient: 1.813 ms.
```

So 'efficient' performs about 8% better.

About the why:

According to Hans Passants answer:

> It basically checks for corner cases, then calls the CRT's version of pow().

So there is some, though minor overhead.

Comment: Could you please add standard deviation to this? If ranges overlap then the real conclusion would be that they are roughly equally fast.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Pow` has to do a few additional checks so it can return correct value if `x < 0` and `toPower` is an integer.

Comment: I hope you're right:  From MSDN: Math.Pow: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx Math.Exp: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.exp.aspx Math.Pow has a lot of checking whereas Math.Exp has none. But is there a way to confirm it?  See David Hefferman doubt below - domain checking may not be the root cause. I'll perform a test again on the native pow() vs. exp()

Answer (score 2):

Hans's answer here ([How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)) explains that `Math.Pow` is not implemented in terms of `Exp` and `Log`. The implementation of `Math.Pow()`, once it has performed domain validation, calls the unmanaged CRT function `pow()`. It is not done that way, I presume, because the CRT `pow()` is more accurate than the `Exp/Log` expression.

So, the reason that `Math.Pow` is slower than the `Exp/Log` variant is that the former does a different calculation that takes longer. And the implementors chose that different calculation because it is more accurate than the `Exp/Log` version. In essence they preferred accuracy to efficiency.

Comment: @DioPhung I'm not convinced that the domain checking is the source of the perf difference. I suspect that a native `pow()` call is more expensive than a native `exp()/ln()` + mult version. That's quite easy to check.