# Comparing Math.Log and Math.Pow

Tags: c#, math, benchmarking, logarithm, pow

I am working with annuities and have the following methods in my code:

```
public static double NumPMTsRemaining( double CurBalance, double ContractRate, double Pmt)
{
    double rt = PeriodicRate(ContractRate);
    return -1 * Math.Log(1 - (CurBalance * (rt) / Pmt)) / Math.Log(1 + (rt));
}

public static double MonthlyPMT(double OrigBalance, double ContractRate, int Term)
{
    double rt = PeriodicRate(ContractRate);
    if (ContractRate > 0)
        return (OrigBalance * rt * Math.Pow(1 + rt, Term)) / (Math.Pow(1 + rt, Term) - 1);
    else return OrigBalance / Term;
}
```

I use the former method to determine if the payment for a loan will insure the loans pays off in its life remaining.  I use the latter method to determine if a payment is quoted for a payment period other than monthly and then replace it with a monthly payment if so.  Upon reflection I can use the latter method for both tasks.

With that in mind, I was wondering if anyone knew off the top of their head if Math.Pow is faster/more efficient than/relative to Math.Log?
I assume that Math.Pow is the better choice, but would appreciate a bit of input.

Comment: Why don't you profile each method with say 100,000 calls and see for yourself which one is faster?

Comment: I'd expect `log` with a fixed base to be faster than `pow`, since pow is usually implemented by calling `log` on the base followed by a fixed base exponentiation function. If you benchmark, benchmark separately for x64 and x86 since the generated floating point code on those platforms is pretty different.

Comment: Unless this is a bottleneck of your application, use the easier to read version, not the faster version.

Comment: I note that `Term` is an integer. There are generally much faster methods than Math.Pow for integer powers see for example http://mindprod.com/jgloss/power.html. Only go this route if this is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Pretty well covered by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870593/17034).  No, Math.Pow() is not faster.  Easy to find out for yourself with the Stopwatch class.

Comment: You should use `Math.Log(x, b)` instead of `Math.Log(x) / Math.Log(b)`, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a benchmark as recommended by @Mangist. The code is posted below.  I was surprised by the response by @CodesInChaos.  I, of course, did some research and realized I could improve a large amount of my code.  I will post a link to a interesting StackOverflow article I found in this regard.  A number of people had worked out improvements on Math.Pow due to the aforementioned fact.

Thank you again for the suggestions and information.

```
        int term = 72;
        double contractRate = 2.74 / 1200;
        double balance = 20203.66;
        double pmt = 304.96;
        double logarithm = 0;
        double power = 0;

        DateTime BeginLog = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            logarithm=(-1*Math.Log(1-(balance*contractRate/pmt))/Math.Log(1+contractRate));
        }
        DateTime EndLog = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time= " + (EndLog - BeginLog));
        Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime BeginPow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            power = (balance * contractRate * Math.Pow(1 + contractRate, term)) / (Math.Pow(1 
                      +  contractRate, term) - 1);
        }
        DateTime EndPow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time= " + (EndPow - BeginPow));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The results of the benchmark were 
Elapsed time for the logarithm 00:00:04.9274927
Elapsed time for the power 00:00:11.6981697

I also alluded to some additional StackOverflow discussions which shed light on the comment by @CodeInChaos.

[How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)

Let me add a head to head comparison between a suggestion on the above link and the Math.Pow function.  I benchmarked Math.Pow(x,y) against Math.Exp(y*Math.Log(x)) with the following code:

```
        DateTime PowBeginTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 250000000; i++)
        {
            Math.Pow(1 + contractRate, term);
        }
        DateTime PowEndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time= " + (PowEndTime - PowBeginTime));
        Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime HighSchoolBeginTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 250000000; i++)
        {
            Math.Exp(term * Math.Log(1 + contractRate));
        }
        DateTime HighSchoolEndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time= " + (HighSchoolEndTime - HighSchoolBeginTime));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The results were:
Math.Pow(x,y)            00:00:19.9469945
Math.Exp(y*Math.Log(x))  00:00:18.3478346

Comment: In your paragraph "The results of the benchmark were Elapsed time for the logarithm 00:00:04.9274927 Elapsed time for the logarithm 00:00:11.6981697" you indicate twice the result for logarithm but none for power.

Comment: Thank you.  The latter should have been power.