# Accessing C# sources

Tags: search

I was just wondering if there is a way to find an algorithm for already existing functions.
For example if I wanted to know how Math.Pow() works the only things googling ever gets me to are the return values and a source code for Math library that defines pow(duble x, double y) as:

```
public static extern double Pow(double x, double y);
```

and nothing else is said about it.
Is there a place where the source codes can be found?

Comment: possibly duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327821/how-can-i-see-the-source-code-of-system-math-sin

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the source directly from .NET Framework because its an `extern` function, meaning it's implemented in a lower-level library--probably the CLR.

You can look at the summary,parameters, and return comments though if that helps you...

1. Hover over the function (In my case Math.Cos) and Hit `F12`
   [image]
2. Expand the comment region in the metadata
   [image]