# Is Math.Pow() slower with big powers than if statements

Tags: c#, performance, math

I am learning C# now, so today I was printing the first n-count of number of this progression:
An = 1/n*(-1)^n; So it basically goes -1 1/2 -1/3 1/4... I was wondering if it is better to use if statements `if(n%2 == 0)` , or the more elegenat `Math.Pow()` method? Is `Math.Pow()` slow even for the number 1, when the power is a big int?

Comment: Since you're learning programming, how about you build a little program to test it out?  Build a big loop (maybe 1 million iterations) and time the results with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`

Comment: You could also consider doing neither, and manually unroll the loop by 2 instead.

Comment: [Does this answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework/8870593#8870593)?

Comment: I wouldn't use Math.pow to alternate a sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd code it this way using the ternary operator:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
   sum += ((i % 2) == 0) ? +1.0 : -1.0)/i;
}
```

I like that loop unrolling idea in the comments, too:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
   sum -= 1.0/i;
}
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) {
   sum += 1.0/i;
}
```

Comment: You may want to mention the `ternary` operator in there.  Not exactly a beginner idea and it's very hard to search for.

Comment: This gets the right idea across, but you are calculating the sum of all An instead of individual An.

Comment: That's true.  I'm showing my math bias: I assumed this was a series sum.  Note the math tag.

Comment: I know precisely what you mean. Just wanted to clarify so that we don't confuse someone who may have meant one or the other.

Comment: Great comment; I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
int sign = -1;
for(int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
{
    double a_n = (double)sign/n;
    sign *= -1;
}
```