# Are there any built-in .NET alternatives for using power of a number (Math.Pow) without errors?

Tags: c#, .net, pow, double-precision

`Math.Pow` seems to be not working correctly for big results. Probably that is because it uses `double` for calculations ([How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)).

For example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine((long)Math.Pow(17, 13));
    Console.WriteLine(Pow(17, 13));
}

public static long Pow(int num, int pow)
{
    long answer = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < pow; i++)
    {
        answer *= num;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

The result from the above code is:

```
9904578032905936
9904578032905937
```

**Are there any built-in .NET alternatives for using power of a number without errors?**

Comment: You see rounding errors. Use `Math.Round()` if you expect an integer result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure has a [`Pow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This structure resides in the `System.Numerics` namespace, and was introduced in .NET Framework 4.0. You need to add a reference to the `System.Numerics` assembly before using it.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Pow(17, 13));   // 9904578032905937
    }
}
```

Note that `BigInteger` is only suitable for integer arithmetic; it cannot handle fractional numbers.