# Math.Ceiling method

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, ceil

I am interessted in the actual `Math.Ceiling` function, how the algorithm behind this function is implemented in the .net framework.
I've checked the function `Math.Ceiling` with a decompiler in mscorlib.dll , - but it seems like it is implemented by native code :

[image]

How can I find out how the algorithm the Ceiling function uses looks like?

Comment: It is an `InternalCall` method. That means it is in CLR written with C++. If you _really_ wanna see it, best option is to get a job at Microsoft CLR Team.

Comment: As an aside, you can also check the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,1841a5ce24ed9fb3) to see the code. Although in this case it gives you nothing more than what you already have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Math.Pow() implemented in .NET Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870442/how-is-math-pow-implemented-in-net-framework)

Comment: This will undoubtedly be implementation specific. There are probably FPUs out there for which this is a single op.

Comment: @Thomas I would say so; otherwise what is to stop someone asking the same question for every method in the class?

Answer (score 4):

Yes for double numbers it's actually [external code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Math.cs#L56):

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern double Ceiling(double a);
```

That means that the method is actually implemented in the CLR, written in C++. The lookup table is located in [clr/src/vm/ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/80c2952d4660cca71f59f305f9e5aae2879473d1/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L1276). The section that's relevant to Math.Ceiling() looks like this:

```
FCFuncStart(gMathFuncs)
  ...
  FCFuncElement("Log10", COMDouble::Log10)
  FCFuncElement("Ceiling", COMDouble::Ceil)
  FCFuncElement("SplitFractionDouble", COMDouble::ModFDouble)
  ...
```

CLR implementation calls native function:

```
FCIMPL1_V(double, COMDouble::Ceil, double d) 
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    return (double) ceil(d);
FCIMPLEND
```

[Here is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) an implementation from `<cmath>`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cfenv>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
double ceil(double x)
{
    double result;
    int save_round = std::fegetround();
    std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    result = std::rint(x); // or std::nearbyint 
    std::fesetround(save_round);
    return result;
}
```

See also [Hans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870593/5649561) for more details.