# Why does pow(x,y) return inf when x and y are chars?

Tags: c, char, pow

I understand how to use `pow()` correctly I'm just wondering why when I run this code `ans` = inf.

I am having a hard time understanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824677/how-is-pow-calculated-in-c/40824889#40824889).

Does this have anything to do with chars only being able to take on the values -128 to +127 and the way `pow()` is calculated?

Does this have anything to do with the space in `" %c"` as in my first `scanf` param?

Linux 4.9.0-7-amd64
debian 4.9.110-1
gcc version 6.3.020170516

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{

    char base, exp; 
    float ans; 

    printf("Enter base number : ");
    scanf(" %c", &base); 

    printf("Enter exp number : ");
    scanf(" %c", &exp); 

    ans = pow(base,exp); 

    printf("%c raised to the %c power equals %f", base, exp, ans);

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enter `base` and `exp` using `%c` you get the *characters* `'0'` - `'9'`, not the integer values.  So if you enter 0 and 0, the values you get (assuming ASCII encoding) will actually by 48, since that is the ASCII code for `'0'`.  The result of 48<sup>48</sup> is roughly 5 x 10<sup>80</sup>.

You then save the resulting value in a `float`.  Assuming a `float` is IEEE754 single precision, it can hold an exponent no larger that +/- 38.  So you're attempting convert an out-of-range value which invokes undefined behavior, meaning the result is unpredictable.  If you changed the type of `ans` to `double` you would see the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

**Base** and **exp** is not the integer values (0-9). So you want to enter "%d". Not the " %c"